# If $N\subset M$, where $M$ is an $R$-module and $rn_1 + n_2 \in N$ for all $n_1,n_2 \in N$ and $r\in R$, then is $N$ a submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Assume that $R$ is a ring that might not have a unit element. What is the correct answer to the following question:

> If $N\subset M$, where $M$ is an $R$-module and $rn_1 + n_2 \in N$ for all $n_1,n_2 \in N$  and $r\in R$, then is $N$ a submodule?

Recall that a subset $N$ of a module $M$ is called a submodule if it is an additive subgroup and $rn$ in $N$ for all $n \in N$ and $r \in R$.

The condition $rn$ in $N$ for all $n \in N$ and $r \in R$ is easy to verify, but it is not clear if $N$ is a subgroup.

[According to Topics in Algebra by Herstein](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMeIZ.png), modules can also be considered over rings that do not have a unit element.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the post via an [edit]. Since you are using a somewhat unusual definition of rings etc, that's highly relevant.

Comment: @Mahesh, can you upload the screenshot of that page? I think you have lack of information within your question

Comment: Right after the definition it says "*All our modules shall be unital ones.*"

Comment: @quid But that doesn't mean all modules are unital .He only means that all module we are going to study are unital .

Comment: I agree, in principle, but this makes the situation pretty confusing. Especially the definition of submodule is given under that assumption.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I have upload the screen shot

Comment: I edited the question a bit and reopened it. I doubt the answer is "yes" if there  is no unit in the ring, I'll think about an example.

Comment: @quid  I will be thankful to you if you provide answer with an example (I will also try) .

Comment: I think the empty set is a trivial counter-example, though I guess that is not what you are aiming at.

Comment: Herstein has always been a bit sloppy in his definitions. But *all our modules shall be unital ones* clearly means that modules are only used in the context of unital rings and they're unital as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one does not impose that the module is unital that's not true anymore. (Whether the ring has a unity or not is not really crucial.)

Let $M=\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the usual addition  yet scalar multiplication  by elements from $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as follows: $r (x_1, x_2) =(rx_1,0)$.

This verifies all conditions in the definition you recall.

Now,  the set $\{(x,y) \colon x \in R, \, y \in \{0,a\}\} \subset M$, where $a$ is some non-zero integer, is a set that verifies the condition in the question yet it is not an additive subgroup.

The very same construction works for other rings too. That the ring has an element whose additive order is greater than $2$ is also that's needed. Thus, we could also work with the ring of even integers for example.